# Excel: combine tables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have N tables with M lines for each table.

For instance I have two tables A and B with respectively 4 lines and 2 lines :

### Table A

### A1

### A2

### A3

### A4

### Table B

### A1

### A2

I want to create a table C, with 4x2 lines and combining all line possibilities :

Table C

### A1 B1

### A1 B2

### A2 B1

### A2 B2

### A3 B1

### A3 B2

### A4 B1

### A4 B2

Is there a way to achieve that with Excel, and if yes, how? Thank you.

Comment: Table B is meant to contain `B1` and `B2`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Say we have two lists like:

[image]

and we want to generate all the combinations of the two lists.  Running this macro:

```
Sub generateCombinations()
    Dim nA As Long, nB As Long, K As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rc As Long
    rc = Rows.Count
    nA = Cells(rc, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    nB = Cells(rc, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1

    For i = 1 To nB
        vb = Cells(i, "B").Value
        For j = 1 To nA
            Cells(K, "C").Value = vb & " " & Cells(j, "A").Value
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce in column **C**:

[image]

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**